# Why Python complains when called method of pybind11 type_cast-ed class that derives from C++ std::vector?

Tags: python, c++, inheritance, stdvector, pybind11

Using `pybind11` I wrap a C++ lib that I cannot modify. An issue came from a class that derives from `std::vector`. (Notes: This my first `pybind11` project. I am not 'fluent' in Python. I was looking for solution on the web but without success.)

Intro. Instance of `E` carries error data. `E` could be instantiated **only** by `Es` - a collector. `Es` gets enlarged with new instances of `E` by method(s) like `addFront(...)` while returning back from failed method(s) (i.e unwinding the call stack).

Minimalistic source code:

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/stl.h>

namespace py = pybind11;
using namespace pybind11::literals;

// Classes
enum class ID { unknown, wrongParam };

class E {
public:
    ID GetID() const { return id; }

protected:
    E( ID _id ) { id = _id; };
    ID  id;
    friend class Es;
};

class Es : public std::vector< E > {
public:
    Es() {}
    Es( ID _id ) { push_back( E( _id ) ); }

    Es& addFront( ID _id ) {
        insert( begin(), E( _id ) );    // Base class methods!
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Since derived from `std::vector`, as I learned, a `type_caster` for `Es` should be applied
so it can be used as a `list` on Python side:

```
namespace pybind11 { namespace detail {
    template <> struct type_caster< Es > : list_caster< Es, E > {};
}} // namespace pybind11::detail
```

The `pybind11` part is:

```
void Bind( py::module_& m ) {
    py::enum_< ID >( m, "ID" )
        .value( "unknown", ID::unknown )
        .value( "wrongParam", ID::wrongParam );

    py::class_< E >( m, "E" )
        .def( "GetID", &E::GetID );

    py::class_< Es >( m, "Es" )
        .def( py::init<>() )
        .def( py::init< ID >(), "id"_a )
        .def( "addFront", &Es::addFront );
}
```

When this Python code is executed:

```python
from AWB import ID, E, Es
es = Es( ID.wrongParam )
es.addFront( ID.unknown )
```

python complains:

```
E:\Projects\AWB>py
Python 3.8.10 (tags/v3.8.10:3d8993a, May  3 2021, 11:48:03) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from AWB import ID, E Es
>>> es = Es( ID.wrongParam )
>>> es.addFront( ID.unknown )
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: addFront(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. (self: List[AWB.E], arg0: AWB.ID) -> List[AWB.E]

Invoked with: <AWB.Es object at 0x000000000260CEB0>, <ID.unknown: 0>
>>>
```

Q: What I am doing wrong?

Q: Why `arg0: AWB.ID` is incompatible with `ID.unknown`?

Q: Maybe the *type casting* should be more precise?

Well, in real world, I don't expect the `Es` will enlarge on Pyhon side. Mostly, I would need to export the collection (in human readble manner) what the `Es` has collected so far (on the C++ side). But since I am writting a test case - I need to be sure it works.

Q: Even if it is possible, to use `addFront`, on Python side, to add an item into C++ `std::vector`... Would it be automatically *visible* in the Python's `list`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to use C++ member functions specific to `Es`, I think you shouldn't try to use type-casting in this case. If you would type-cast `Es`, that means your Python type will be a copied list of `E` objects but it wouldn't have methods like `addFront` - you'll have `append` etc.

What you can do is to wrap your type [as an opaque type](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/cast/stl.html#making-opaque-types), and export the methods you need. This example is from the pybind11 documentation:

```cpp
py::class_<std::vector<int>>(m, "IntVector")
    .def(py::init<>())
    .def("clear", &std::vector<int>::clear)
    .def("pop_back", &std::vector<int>::pop_back)
    .def("__len__", [](const std::vector<int> &v) { return v.size(); })
    .def("__iter__", [](std::vector<int> &v) {
       return py::make_iterator(v.begin(), v.end());
    }, py::keep_alive<0, 1>()) /* Keep vector alive while iterator is used */
    // ....
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [unddoch answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69325936/2135295), I slightly reworked the code. Here are the changes that might be of help for others.

First, replace the `type_caster` block of code with:

```
PYBIND11_MAKE_OPAQUE(Es);
```

and if binding instructions for `py::class_<Es>(m, "Es")` are enlarged with:

```
    .def("__len__", [](const Es& v) {return v.size();})
```

the Python sequence executes as:

```
>>> from AWB import ID, E, Es
>>> es = Es(ID.wrongParam)
>>> es = es.addFront(ID.unknown)
>>> len(es)
2
```